# JavaFX: How can I get the character the represents the platform specific SHORTCUT key code?

Tags: java, javafx, keycode

I am writing a JavaFX application and I have used accelerators to add shortcut keys to the application menus.

Now I am creating the application help and I want to describe the usage of the shortcut keys.

The recommendation for JavaFX accelerators is to use `SHORTCUT` instead of `CONTROL` (Windows) and `COMMAND` (Apple). This works fine and in the menus when running the application on different platforms show the right key combination.

For example, `MenuItem Exit` I have added the accelerator `SHORTCUT_DOWN + X` which is displayed as

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> under Windows

and

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> under Mac OS

Now I would like to get the explanations (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) from the system in order to add it to the user help.

Is it possible to ask JavaFX for the presentation of the accelerator in the menu? Or get the presentation of `SHORTCUT_DOWN` used in the menus?

Thx in advance

Thorsten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, the [`getDisplayText()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCombination.html#getDisplayText--)

> Returns a string representation of this KeyCombination that is suitable for display in a user interface (for example, beside a menu item).

So all you need is

```
String acceleratorAsString = menuItem.getAccelerator().getDisplayText();
```